# Python: fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Tags: python

I got the below error:

> note: python38.lib(python38.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine
>   type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Knowing that my Win 10 is x64 and installed python is the one for x64

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you are using x86 C/C++ compiler instead of x64.

Try adding PATH variable of folder containing your x64 compiler and moving that variable to the top of the list